# How to retrieve information from the last order in Magento 2.3

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I want to fetch information from the last request made by the client in magento 2.3

When editing the success.phtml page you need to show me some information about completing the request as the total value of the request and address, I looked at some tutorials that say they work with the script below.

```
$status = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('entity_id', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    ->getFirstItem()
    ->getPrice();
```

The code is not retrieving any information.

Comment: Please provide a little more clarification on the issue you are having. Is `NO RESULT RECOVERED` an error or unexpected message?

Comment: thanks, edited.I Inserting this code it returns no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to use an **Observer**, to intercept the order data that has just been purchased and then with the order data you can implement the features that are required.

events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="yourcompany_yourmodule_checkout_submit_all_after" instance="YourCompany\YourModule\Observer\ProcessOrder" />
    </event>

</config>
```

And the Observer

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    // Do whatever you want here
    return $this;
}
```